# use AudioContext in angular2 with typescript

Tags: audio, typescript, angular

i have a little test project going on. it's a angular2/typescript (to es5) application built with gulp.

when i am creating a webaudio audiocontext (coming form typescript lib) in an angular component with

```
let context = new AudioContext();
```

things work out as planned on desktop browsers. everythings runs beautifully ... but on mobile devices AudioContext can not be found and throws a reference error. what is the best way of using the webaudio api and getting the audiocontext in a build like that?

Comment: This is not Angular or TypeScript related. The browser probably just doesn't have AudioContext()? What browser did you try? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext

Comment: latest safari and chrome for ios 9.2.1

Comment: i expected typescript to wrap this functionality but the error comes earlier.. AudioContext (the typescript function) cannot be found

Comment: According to the link above Safari doesn't support it. TypeScript doesn't wrap browser API. If you import a library and call its API then there is some abstraction, the browser API is exposed directly.

Comment: this is what i am talking about
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L4468

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YhUFfo?p=preview (see src/app.ts in the constructor) Seems to work fine.

Comment: As Gunter said this is not related to TS nor Angular2. Just check [caniuse for audio api](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio-api), it's supported in Safari and iOS with `webkit` prefix, check this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

Comment: thank u all.. what i didnt know is, that a chrome browser under ios is built on top of the safari engine..